# Hex Formatting of integer

Tags: python

I feel this is very simple thing to do but I cannot get this to the proper format.

I am trying to get the integer 10 into `'\x0A` I got it to 0xa with `hex(10)`, but this is not what I need.

Is there a simple way to get the string that I am looking for?

It won't always be ten, the number could be from 7 to 50

Comment: You understand that "\x0A" is a single character, right?

Comment: Yeah, 0xa is "10" in hex. Like Ignacio says, that's just one character. You are just looking at the "text representation" of that character. Why do you think it's not getting converted to hex? What are you trying to do? This sounds like an X/Y problem so far.

Comment: You may be looking for the `chr` function. It converts 10 to `'\x0a'`.

Comment: chr is what I was looking for.  Thanks, didn't understand the different representation from typing to the display of print.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just so you know, `chr` has nothing to do with hex formatting. it simply converts a number to a character. `'\x0a'` is just one way of representing a character literal that happens to use hex, but this is not how it is stored.